# Twisting words! (boustrophedon formatting)

Tags: strings, ruby, programming-challenge, formatting, rags-to-riches

I decided to implement properly the [Code Golf challenge](//codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/55051) about twisting strings. I report the assignement verbatim for convenience:

> ## Twisting Words!
>
> Given a string and a positive integer. You must twist the string, back
>   and forth.
>
> ### Example Input / Output
>
> #### Input
>
> ```
> Programming Puzzles & Code Golf
> 4
> ```
>
> #### Output
>
> ```
> Prog
> mmar
> ing 
> zzuP
> les 
> oC &
> de G
>  flo
> ```
>
> ### Input
>
> The input can be taken in through STDIN, or function argument. The
>   input will consist of a string and a positive integer, *n*. The
>   integer will determine the length of each twisted line.
>
> The string is twisted back-and-forth. An input of `HELLO, WORLD!` and
>   5 would look like:
>
> [image: HELLO, WORLD!]
>
> ### Output
>
> The output will be the twisted text. It may not any trailing
>   whitespace. If the input string length is not divisible be the line
>   length, add a space until the line is filled:
>
> An example of this:    Input
>
> ```
> Hello, World!
> 5
> ```
>
> Output (Note the whitespace at the very end)
>
> ```
> Hello
> roW ,
> ld!
> ```

**My implementation**

```ruby
def twist(text, chunk_size)
   text
     .+(" " * ((text.length % chunk_size) - 1))
     .chars
     .each_slice(chunk_size)
     .each_with_index
     .map {|str, i| i.odd? ? str.reverse : str}
     .map(&:join)
     .join("\n")
end

puts twist("Hello, World!", 5)
puts
puts twist("foo bar baz", 7)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks fine to me. Only thing I'd change is the way the padding is done: You can use [`ljust`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html#method-i-ljust) instead, which seems a little more appropriate to me. Something like:

```
.ljust(text.length.fdiv(chunk_size).ceil * chunk_size, " ")
```

You can also use the `with_index` modifier on `map` instead of doing a separate `each_with_index`, i.e.:

```
.map.with_index { |chunk, index| index.odd? ? chunk.reverse : chunk }
```

---

Of course there are several approaches to this. For instance, you needn't necessarily use `chars` and then `join`. For instance:

```
def twist(text, chunk_size)
  text
    .ljust(text.length.fdiv(chunk_size).ceil * chunk_size, " ")
    .scan(%r/.{#{chunk_size}}/)
    .map.with_index { |chunk, index| index.odd? ? chunk.reverse : chunk }
    .join("\n")
end
```

I won't say it's a better solution, though. Fewer lines, sure, but the interpolated regex isn't pretty. But again, it's just to show an alternative approach.

You can also move the `ljust`, to avoid the long'ish bit of arithmetic:

```
def twist(text, chunk_size)
  text
    .scan(%r/.{1,#{chunk_size}}/)
    .map { |chunk| chunk.ljust(chunk_size, " ") }
    .map.with_index { |chunk, index| index.odd? ? chunk.reverse : chunk }
    .join("\n")
end
```

It's obviously it's kinda brute-force, since we know that it'd only be the last chunk that could require padding. But again: Just an alternative.

Comment: I like this answer, just a pair of questions: I would replace `text.length.fdiv(chunk_size).ceil * chunk_size` with `text.length + text.length % chunk_size` which one would be better? Could you please explain the interpolated regex approach? I do not understand it

Comment: @Caridorc Yours is better - should've figured that one myself, but I was a little too tired, I guess :)   As for the regex: If `chunk_size` is 4, the regex ends up being `.{4}` (or `.{1,4}` in the last code block). That basically means "match 4 characters of any kind" (or "match 1-4 characters..."). The `%r/.../` is just Ruby syntax for declaring a regex pattern, but it allows you to use `#{..}` interpolation, like you can with strings. You can also use `%r[..]` or `%r(..)` or `%r{..}`- I picked slashes for readability. Similar to the `%w` syntax for split-on-whitespace lists. Make sense?

Comment: More clear now, the same as `.scan(Regexp("." * chunk_size))` rigth?

Comment: @Caridorc Yup, exactly

Comment: Perfect, I will wait a day or two before accepting.